# TrueType font not rendering correctly to pdf from SSRS

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts

I have True Type Font Verlag installed on my Developer machine & SSRS Server.  The Font embeddability value = "Preview/Print"

When I render to pdf from inside Visual Studio it renders correctly.

When I deploy the report to the SSRS Server and render to Excel it's correct, but when I render to pdf, the font reverts to default font.

I have read many similar questions but found no solution.  It looks as if it should correctly embed the font into the pdf (thus making it unnecessary for the client to have it installed on their machine.)  But it's not even displaying it on the

Comment: If restarting the SQL Reporting Service doesn't work, you can try rebooting the machine.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem even though I had installed the font. In the end, it was because I had not installed the font for all users.